# How to decode a variable string from C?

Tags: python, c

Trying to program an UDP connection. The client is in python and the server is in C.

In my python code I defined my PDU as a struct (using the struct module) in this format: **'B 5s 50s'** `(unsigned char, char[5], char[50])`. The issue is that if the strings are not filled, the remainder is garbage, which I should remove.

After unpacking the response from server, if I do:

```
str = str_from_c.split('\0',1)
```

It returns me this:

```
['useful data', '\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00\xae\xf2d\xb7\x18\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x94\xecd\xb7\xa8\xe6\xb0\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa9]\xb7\xca\xf1d\xb7']
```

How I can dispose the second part?

Comment: "*How I can despise the second part?*" Just do not send it?

Comment: The server have the same struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *despise* do you mean *dispose*? If you just want the text, then only take that from the result - note we're not calling the variable `str` here as that will shadow the builtin `str`:

```
text, rest = str_from_c.split('\0', 1)
```

Then just use `text` and if you need `rest` you've got it for later...

Note that in the case of splitting once, then `str.partition` is preferred, eg:

```
text, rest = str_from_c.partition('\0')[::2]
```

As this ensures there's always a 3-tuple result so that unpacking will always be successful even if no actual split occurred.

Comment: I see. Then my split is fine?

Comment: @LiLou_ If splitting on NUL is the way to delimit between useful text and the remainder of message, then it's fine... Just ignore the bit you're not interested in... I would recommend using `str.partition` as shown above though instead of `str.split`

Answer (score 0):

> How I can despise the second part?

Just do not send it?

The server code probably looks like this:

```
char buffer[123];
<init buffer partially, terminating the the part with a 0 >

write(..., buffer, 123);
```

Change it to be

```
write(..., buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
```